# Get percent of column value count compared to same column value count in another table during certain time period grouping by column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, outer-join

Looking for share of each `Agent`'s rows where `task` = 'Stalking' in table `Stalking` compared to occurrences in table `Assigned` during Min and Max `stalkDate` in table `Stalking`.

Table `Assigned`

| Agent | task | taskDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dbl07 | Stalking | 2019-12-01 |
| dbl07 | patrol | 2020-06-01 |
| dbl07 | travel | 2020-06-24 |
| dbl07 | Stalking | 2021-10-01 |
| dbl07 | Stalking | 2021-12-01 |
| dbl07 | Stalking | 2022-12-24 |
| dbl07 | travel | 2022-12-01 |
| mrBourne | train | 2021-06-06 |
| mrBourne | Stalking | 2022-06-06 |
| mrSmart | Stalking | 2018-01-01 |
| mrSmart | idle | 2021-06-06 |
| mrSmart | Stalking | 2021-01-01 |
| mrSmart | Stalking | 2022-06-06 |
| mrEnglish | lurk | 2022-06-06 |
| mrEnglish | jest | 2022-06-06 |

Table `Stalking`,    -- `stalkDate` min-max =  `2020-01-31`  -  `2022-12-31`

| Agent | stalkDate |
| --- | --- |
| dbl07 | 2020-01-31 |
| dbl07 | 2022-12-31 |
| mrBourne | 2022-06-30 |
| mrSmart | 2022-06-30 |
| mrEnglish | 2022-06-30 |
| mrPowers | 2022-06-06 |

Result should be:

| Agent | prcnt |
| --- | --- |
| dbl07 | 66.66 |
| mrBourne | 100.00 |
| mrSmart | 50.00 |
| mrEnglish | 100.00 |
| mrPowers | 00.00 |

note: `taskDate` in `Assigned` and stalkDate in `Stalking` are not in sync, the search is made by selecting MIN and MAX `stalkDate` from `Stalking`.

```
SELECT 
    s.Agent, 
        (CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(s.Agent))/
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(a.Agent))
        ) * 100 as prcnt
FROM 
    Stalking s
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Assigned a ON s.Agent = a.Agent
WHERE 
    a.task = 'Stalking' 
    AND a.taskDate >= (SELECT MIN(stalkDate) FROM Stalking)
    AND a.taskDate <= (SELECT MAX(stalkDate) FROM Stalking)
GROUP BY
    s.Agent, a.task, a.taskDate
```

I have 3 problems

1. For each `Agent` query results in `prcnt` = 100.00
2. How to handle "divide by zero" in case of mrEnglish and assign him `prcnt` = 100.00?
3. How to get `prcnt` = 00.00 to mrPowers? He has no record in `Assigned`.

Comment: `(COUNT(a.Agent) / COUNT(b.Agent)` will return in an **integer** value, likely either `1` or `0`, as you are dividing an `int` by another. Casting an `int` to a `decimal` won't add precision that has already been lost. `CONVERT(decimal(10,2),(19/10) * 100 )= 100.00` -> `CONVERT(decimal(10,2),1 *100) = CONVERT(decimal(10,2),100) = 100.00`. `CAST` the value *before* the division.

Comment: Changed it to  `(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(a.Agent))/
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(b.Agent))  ) * 100 as prcnt`

But I'm still getting 100.00 for each Agent

Comment: Choose table aliases that make sense, e.g. `a` for `Assigned`...

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Comment: In JOIN I usually use `a` for left side, `b` for right. Popped into my mind to change it but was selfish and thought comparing to real data query would be simpler.

Comment: Yeah, I was unsure whether or not to `GROUP BY` all three. I tried with `GOURP BY` with onle a.Agent. Same result.

Comment: For the sample data you've given, I don't get *any* results... The attempt actually contains a syntax error, but if i fix that nothing comes back. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AxnKsjJP) Something isn't right here, the SQL doesn't behave as you state it does.

Comment: Why do you use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` here as well, when you require several columns in the table `b` to have a non-`NULL` value; it's *impossible* for `b.task = 'Stalk'` to be true is no rows were found in "`b`" for `Assigned` (personally I'd say "A" is for Assigned, but you have "a" for st**a**lking for some odd reason).

Comment: Made corrections to question: 
`(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(s.Agent))/
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),COUNT(a.Agent))`
and 
`b.task = 'Stalk'`  →  `b.task = 'Stalking'`

Comment: Changed aliases  `a` for `Assigned`, `s` for `Stalking`

Comment: I'm experimenting. I don't fully know how different JOINs behave in this query. I've tried other JOINS too. `FULL OUTER JOIN` was my last try.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data:

```
create table #Assigned
(
    Agent varchar(20),
    task varchar(20),
    taskDate date
)

create table #Stalking
(
    Agent varchar(20),
    stalkDate date
)

insert into #Assigned values
('dbl07',    'Stalking','2019-12-01'),
('dbl07',    'patrol',  '2020-06-01'),
('dbl07',    'travel',  '2020-06-24'),
('dbl07',    'Stalking','2021-10-01'),
('dbl07',    'Stalking','2021-12-01'),
('dbl07',    'Stalking','2022-12-24'),
('dbl07',    'travel',  '2022-12-01'),
('mrBourne', 'train',   '2021-06-06'),
('mrBourne', 'Stalking','2022-06-06'),
('mrSmart',  'Stalking','2018-01-01'),
('mrSmart',  'idle',    '2021-06-06'),
('mrSmart',  'Stalking','2021-01-01'),
('mrSmart',  'Stalking','2022-06-06'),
('mrEnglish','lurk',    '2022-06-06'),
('mrEnglish','jest',    '2022-06-06')

insert into #Stalking values
('dbl07',    '2020-01-31'),
('dbl07',    '2022-12-31'),
('mrBourne', '2022-06-30'),
('mrSmart',  '2022-06-30'),
('mrEnglish','2022-06-30'),
('mrPowers', '2022-06-06')
```

You can get do something like:

```
select distinct
    ag.Agent,
    mm.minDate,
    mm.maxDate,
    tot.numRecords,
    isnull(tot.numStalking,0) as numStalking,
    case when tot.numRecords = 0 or isnull(tot.numStalking,0) = 0
        then '0.00%'
        else format(convert(decimal(10,2),isnull(tot.numStalking,0)) / convert(decimal(10,2),tot.numRecords),'P')
    end as prcnt
from 
(select distinct Agent from #Stalking) ag
left join #Assigned a on ag.Agent = a.Agent
outer apply
(
    select 
        min(stalkDate) as minDate,
        max(stalkDate) as maxDate
    from #Stalking s
    where s.Agent = a.Agent
) mm
outer apply
(
    select 
        count(*) as numRecords,
        sum(case when ass.task = 'Stalking' then 1 else 0 end) as numStalking
    from #Assigned ass
    where ass.taskDate >= mm.minDate
    and ass.taskDate <= mm.maxDate
    and a.Agent = ass.Agent
) tot
```

which gives the output:

| Agent | minDate | maxDate | numRecords | numStalking | prcnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbl07 | 31/01/2020 | 31/12/2022 | 6 | 3 | 50.00% |
| mrBourne | 30/06/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0.00% |
| mrEnglish | 30/06/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0.00% |
| mrPowers | NULL | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0.00% |
| mrSmart | 30/06/2022 | 30/06/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0.00% |

This actually differs from your stated expected output, but looking at your example data, I believe 50% is the correct percentage for `dbl07` as they have 6 records in `Assigned` which fall into their range of dates in `Stalking`, three of which have the `task` value of `"Stalking"`.

There might be a more elegant way to do this without `OUTER APPLY` (perhaps using Window Functions), but this is just the method which came to mind.